# wavesurfer.js produces no sound

Tags: wavesurfer.js

Can you tell me why this doesn't produce sound?
It all look fine. I couldn;t post the full code, this forum doesn;t allow it.

Is this only to work with servers?

I have tried but nothing works, this is as far I could go.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>WaveSurfer.js Example</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@7"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    html, body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0.5rem;
      font-family: sans-serif;
      background-color: transparent;
      font-size: 16px;
    }
    input {
      vertical-align: text-top;
    }
    @media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
      body {
        background: #333;
        color: #eee;
      }
      a {
        color: #fff;
      }
    }
  </style>
  
  <script type="module" data-type="module">
    // Web Audio example

    import WaveSurfer from 'https://unpkg.com/wavesurfer.js@7/dist/wavesurfer.esm.js'

  (...)

    // Create a vertical slider for each band
    const container = document.createElement('p')
    filters.forEach((filter) => {
      const slider = document.createElement('input')
      slider.type = 'range'
      slider.orient = 'vertical'
      slider.style.appearance = 'slider-vertical'
      slider.style.width = '8%'
      slider.min = -40
      slider.max = 40
      slider.value = filter.gain.value
      slider.step = 0.1
      slider.oninput = (e) => (filter.gain.value = e.target.value)
      container.appendChild(slider)
    })
    document.body.appendChild(container)
  </script>
 
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

I am not sure if I am missing some dependencies, or if this requires a sever to work at all.
I have tried but nothing works, this is as far I could go.